# Printing a circle on the terminal with a 2D array in C

Tags: c, ascii, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to print a circle to the terminal using the formula:

x = r * sin(angle) && y = r * cos(angle)

but for some reason the output circle comes out as an oval shape not a perfect circle..

```
     ##########                                                                                     
    ##        ##                                                                                    
  ##            ##                                                                                  
  #              #                                                                                  
 #                #                                                                                 
##                ##                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
#                  #                                                                                
##                ##                                                                                
 #                #                                                                                 
  #              #                                                                                  
  ##            ##                                                                                  
    ##        ##                                                                                    
     ##########                                                                                     
          #
```

I don't know how this happened is the problem with my code or with my formula?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float angle = 0;
    float sinAngle, cosAngle;

    int r = 10;
    int origin = 50;

    static char plane[100][100];
    memset(plane, ' ', sizeof(plane));
    
    for (float counter = 0; counter < 360; counter++ && angle++)
    {
        sinAngle = sin(angle);
        cosAngle = cos(angle);

        int x = (r * sinAngle) + 10;
        int y = (r * cosAngle) + 90;
    
        plane[y][x] = '#';
    }
        
    for (int counter_1 = 0; counter_1 < 100; counter_1++)
    {
        for (int counter_2 = 0; counter_2 <100; counter_2++)
        {
            printf("%c", plane[counter_1][counter_2]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not really doing anything wrong. The problem is simply that the characters are larger in height than in width. It is a circle; it just doesn't look that way.

Comment: You need to take the "aspect ratio" into account; scale the axes. But broadly speaking, one line takes about the same room vertically as two characters horizontally, so you can just double the x-coordinate to get a better representation.

Comment: If you tip the monitor back about 64 degrees, it will look like a circle.  ;-)  (About a 2:1 aspect ratio.)

Comment: Thank you, both of you! adjusting the aspect ratio solved my problem ✨

Comment: Aside: why are you using `float`? Never use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C. Old teaching material isn't a 'good reason'. You don't use `short` instead of `int` just because the range is small without a good reason.

Comment: I just like going easy on memory like I won't be using ```long``` if I'm expecting an input of a number from 0 to 9, same thing with me choosing ```float``` over ```double```, I don't need extreme precision I just need to represent a ```floating point number``` to the precision of 2 decimal places.. I could be wrong tho but why would you risk taking ```more space for precision``` if you don't need it?

Comment: Going easy on memory?! Really? Then why do you allocate 10,000 bytes and only use 400 for this "circle" with a diameter of 20?

Comment: BTW: The functions `sin()` and `cos()` expect the parameter to be in `radians`, not `degrees` ... AND, `counter++ && angle++`??? You probably want to replace the `&&` with an ordinary comma (`,`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use constants (or sizeof0 instead of magic values.
2. As discussed above multiply x with the aspect ratio of your font which is ~2.
3. Minimized scope of variables.
4. Eliminated the `counter` variable, and switched angle to radians. 5. Instead of 360 iterations we can get with half that.
5. Tweaked X_OFFSET and Y_OFFSET to avoid clipping but added support for clipping to avoid accidental out of bounds writes.
6. Use `round()` result in a better circle than truncating `x` and `y`.
7. Output a line at a time.

```
#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ASPECT_RATIO 2
#define ITERATIONS 180
#define R 10
#define X_LEN 100
#define X_OFFSET 20
#define Y_LEN 100
#define Y_OFFSET 80

int clip(int v, int max) {
    return v < max ? v : max - 1;
}

int main(void) {
    char plane[Y_LEN][X_LEN];
    memset(plane, ' ', sizeof plane);
    for (double angle = 0; angle < 2 * M_PI; angle += 2 * M_PI / ITERATIONS) {
        int x = clip(round(ASPECT_RATIO * R * sin(angle) + X_OFFSET), X_LEN);
        int y = clip(round(R * cos(angle) + Y_OFFSET), Y_LEN);
        plane[y][x] = '#';
    }
    for (int counter_1 = 0; counter_1 < Y_LEN; counter_1++) {
        printf("%.*s\n", X_LEN, plane[counter_1][counter_2]);
    }
}
```

and the result:

```
              #############                                                                         
          ####             ####                                                                     
       ###                     ###                                                                  
     ###                         ###                                                                
   ###                             ###                                                              
  ##                                 ##                                                             
 ##                                   ##                                                            
 #                                     #                                                            
##                                     ##                                                           
#                                       #                                                           
#                                       #                                                           
#                                       #                                                           
##                                     ##                                                           
 #                                     #                                                            
 ##                                   ##                                                            
  ##                                 ##                                                             
   ###                             ###                                                              
     ###                         ###                                                                
       ###                     ###                                                                  
          ####             ####                                                                     
              #############
```

If you want you could replace `cos(angle)` with `sin(angle + M_PI/2)`.

Circles are symmetric so you could just calculate, say, only the top half (`angle < M_PI`) to populate the whole thing.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.